# Removing all files but those with video extension

Tags: java

I'm trying to delete every file from a directory (and it's subdirectories, very important) which isn't a video file.Here is my ProcessDirectory class:

```
public class ProcessDirectory {
private File directory;
public static final String [] MOVIE_EXTENSIONS = {"avi", "mp4", "flv", "mkv"};


public ProcessDirectory(String path) {
    this.directory = new File(path);
}

private Collection<File> findMovieFiles() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Getting all .avi, .mp4 files in " + this.directory.getCanonicalPath()
            + " including those in subdirectories");
    Collection<File> videoFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(this.directory, MOVIE_EXTENSIONS, true);


    return videoFiles;
}

public void removeAllNonMovieFiles() throws IOException {
    Collection<File> movieFiles = findMovieFiles();
    Collection<File> allFilesAndFolders = FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs(this.directory, TrueFileFilter.TRUE, TrueFileFilter.TRUE);

    // have to use Iterator because otherwise it throws ConcurrentModificationException
    Iterator<File> iter = allFilesAndFolders.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        File currentElement = iter.next();
        if (!movieFiles.contains(currentElement)) {
            iter.remove();
        }
    }

}
```

}

And here is where I call the method:

```
String path = "/run/media/michal/F04AA6E24AA6A536/Filmy/FilmyTest/";
    ProcessDirectory directory = new ProcessDirectory(path);

    try {
        directory.removeAllNonMovieFiles();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It doesn't seem to work - no files are deleted. Both of my Collections are fine - checked them all with System.out and they have correct files in them, but they arent removing anything.

EDIT: Changed my code, I think it looks better now now but still doesn't work.

Comment: Add some logs (or System.out) before and after the `videoFiles.removeIf` to see the size of this Collection. You will see if the `videoFiles` is correctly set up.

Comment: I changed my code if you are still interested in helping me out :)

Comment: But now, you do not have anymore a `file.delete()`, that was existing in your previous code.  What happens if you add `currentElement.delete();` just before the `iter.remove();` ? In debug mode, did you try to see if you enter in the `if` statement ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iter.remove()` just removes the file from the collection. You are missing the part where the files are actually deleted, like `Files.delete` or something like that.

Do you know `java.nio.file.Files`? With it you can even write code like the following:

```
Files.walk(Paths.get("your path here"))
     .filter(isNotAMovieFile())
     .forEach(delete());
```

This way you only need to implement `Predicate<Path> isNotAMovieFile()` and `Consumer<Path> delete()` which should be pretty much straight-forward.

Comment: I thought that collection is like image 1:1 of actual files but it's actually like parsed names from those objects? If I for example wanted to rename some files I couldn't just do Collection.rename but had to access them with Files.rename or some other function which actually interacts with Files?

Comment: the collection contains the `File` objects representing the actual files. The collection is just a generic container, which could contain any object. As such there is no way for the collection to know, what it should do on a remove, except removing the object from that collection.